# Incorrect pixel size for same height in ListView: how to enforce pixel height/size

Tags: wpf, listview, user-controls, dpi

I have a `ListView` that hosts multiple instances of an user control in a C# WPF application.

This user control displays a horizontal line that always has the same size "1".

However on screen, the lines that should have the same height display with +/-1 pixel height difference!!!

[image: First line is thicker]

[image: First two lines are thinner!!!]

**Question**: How can I enforce that rendering will render the lines with the same PIXEL height?!

Here the Line definition in the user control:

Line definition of the user control:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row         = "1"
           Grid.Column      = "0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan  = "2"
           Fill             = "DodgerBlue"
           Height           = "1"
           Margin           = "0, 1, 0, 2" />
```

and the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource                   = "{Binding FoundBooks, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem                  = "{Binding SelectedBookPreview}"
          Grid.Row                      = "1" 
          Grid.Column                   = "0" 
          SelectionMode                 = "Single"
          HorizontalContentAlignment    = "Stretch">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vmLessonBookPreview}">
            <ucont:ucLessonBookListViewItem DataContext         = "{Binding}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch" 
                                            Margin              = "-3, 0, -3, 0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

More notes;

- The line-height does only depend on the display position in the control, not on the index number (so first line will always have same size different than 2nd line for example, even when I scroll)
- Tested with `ListView`, `ItemsControl` and `ComboBox`, all the same issues
- Controls added manually in a `ScrollViewer` do not behave like this
- Using px sizes (e.g. `Height = "2px"` does not change anything!)

It really seems to be an issue with the ItemsControl presenter, could it be a bug?

Comment: Haven't tested anything myself, but have you tried [`SnapsToDevicePixels`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels) yet?

Comment: Tried setting this to the concerned rectangle and all parent controls including the user control without success so far...

Comment: Side note: when I set a fixed height for the user control in the ItemTemplate depending in the height I get more or less of the lines displayed with the same amount of pixels...

Comment: The issue is clearly related to any ItemControl derived object. When I place the items in a ScrollViewer (adding them manually x times) they all display the same as expected! Strangely I can't find similar issues searching the net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the solution was really simple although finding it was more luck than anything else...

I just had to add UseLayoutRounding to the Rectangle control...:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row             = "1"
           Grid.Column          = "0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan      = "2"
           Fill                 = "DodgerBlue"
           UseLayoutRounding    = "True" 
           Height               = "1"
           Margin               = "0, 1, 0, 2" />
```

I hope it will help others too!

Comment: Nice, here's some more information on that if anyone's wondering lik I was: [UseLayoutRounding vs. SnapsToDevicePixels](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/12/20/454-uselayoutrounding-vs-snapstodevicepixels/)